# SQL to compare one two ranges of numbers to each other, looking for overlap

Tags: c#, sql

An simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

If I have two ranges of numbers, such as

beginningA, endingA (this is the range that I want to compare to the database to check for overlap)

beginningB, endingB (this is the range that is already in the database)

Can I compare them to look for overlap without looping or making lists  (my database will be unmanageable if I go that route)?

I can get this to work if I use a list for the first range, and have a table containing each number as a record for the second range.  However, the table that would contain the already-used serial numbers will end up containing millions of rows, which is why I'm trying to avoid this route.

```
 public static string VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(int beginning, int ending)
        {

            OleDbConnection connection = BadgeDatabaseDB.GetConnection();

            string checkStatement
                = "SELECT OrderNumber, MfgBeginningSerial, MfgEndingSerial "
                + "FROM Orders "
                + "WHERE MfgBeginningSerial "
                + "BETWEEN @beginning AND @ending "
                + "OR MfgEndingSerial "
                + "BETWEEN @beginning AND @ending";


            OleDbCommand selectCommand =
                new OleDbCommand(checkStatement, connection);

            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@beginning", beginning);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ending", ending);

            // default string if no duplicates found
            string duplicateSerials = "No duplicates found.";

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    duplicateSerials 
                        = "There is overlap with: \n\n     Order #  "
                        + dataReader["OrderNumber"].ToString()
                        + "\n     Serial #'s "
                        + dataReader["MfgBeginningSerial"].ToString()
                        + " - "
                        + dataReader["MfgEndingSerial"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return duplicateSerials;
        }
```

This returns a string that says there is overlap with an order, even though there is no overlap.  Perhaps it's just my syntax?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help... Do you consider it an overlap if the very ends match, e.g. do 1 .. 3 and 3 .. 4 overlap for you? Do 1 .. 3 and 0 .. 1?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot, false alarm.  This works, but I had the database serial number fields as text, and the new numbers as integers.  Once I changed the database fields to numbers, I'm getting the expected results.

As FYI, I'm using an Access database, and yes, I did want the end numbers to be included.

Thanks.